# Callback data out of mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, koa

I want to use koa with mongodb and mongoose with the following code:

```
var getMessage = function*(params) {
  var messages = MessageModel.find({
    to: params.to
  }, function(err, m) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    // How to get the data out of here to work with them?
    console.log(m);
  });

  yield messages.fields;
}

app.get('/message/to/:to', function*(next) {
  this.body =
    yield getMessage(this.params);
});
```

The function itself works. That means, that the data are printed on the console, but I don't know how to get the data out of the function, to work with them. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disclaimer: I do not know koa.

Have you tried to yield the promise itself? https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1859

```
var getMessage = function*(params) {
  var mPromise = MessageModel.find({
    to: params.to
  }).exec();
  yield mPromise;    
}

app.get('/message/to/:to', function*(next) {
  this.body =
    yield getMessage(this.params);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped a lot. With the exec() function, it worked. :)

Comment: In addition. The only thing I had to do was to edit the line "this.body = yield getMessage(this.params)" to "this.body = yield getMessage(this.params).next();". With the "next()" the data is shown.

Answer (score 4):

You would either use the promise returned by `.find().exec()`  without a generator:

```
var getMessage = function (params) {
  return MessageModel.find({
    to: params.to
  }).exec();  
}

app.get('/message/to/:to', function*(next) {
  this.body = yield getMessage(this.params);
});
```

or yield the promise inside the generator and return the value you want:

```
var getMessage = function*(params) {
  var data = yield MessageModel.find({
    to: params.to
  }).exec();

  return data;
}
```

Have a look at http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/12/21/experiments-with-koa-and-javascript-generators/ for more info on what you can yield.